# Norm of analytic matrix-valued function on a compact interval

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $M :  \Omega \to \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $n\geq 1$, $\Omega := [0,a] \subset \mathbb{R}$, $a>0$ be a matrix-valued function, that we further assume is analytic in $\Omega$.

Consider the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)$ with the usual topology. Here $M$ defines an operator $\tilde{M} : L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)$, given by $(\tilde{M}f)(t) = M(t)f(t)$ (a.e.), for all $f \in L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)$.

As far as I know, the 'natural' way to define the norm of $\tilde{M}$ is by the uniform operator topology,
\begin{align}
||\tilde{M}|| &= \sup_{||f||=1} ||Mf||_{L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{C}^n)} \\
&= \sup_{||f||=1} \sqrt{\langle Mf, Mf \rangle} \\
&= \sup_{||f||=1} \sqrt{ \int_0^a f^\dagger(t) M^\dagger(t) M(t) f(t) dt}.
\end{align}

So far so good, but then:

> How is the expression above related to something we can compute in terms of just $M(t)$? For instance, how is it related to its pointwise Frobenius norm? E.g. does the following formula hold:
>    \begin{equation}
>  ||\tilde{M}|| \leq \alpha ~ \sup_{t \in \Omega}  ||M(t)||_F,
> \end{equation}
>   for some constant $\alpha$, where $||M(t)||_F = \sqrt{Tr(M^\dagger(t)M(t))}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it holds
$$
\|M(t)f(t)\|_2 \le \|M(t)\|_2 \|f(t)\|_2 \le \|M(t)\|_F \|f(t)\|_2,
$$
and hence we obtain
$$
\|\tilde M f\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_\Omega f(t)^TM(t)^TM(t)f(t)dt
\le \int_\Omega \|M(t)\|_2^2 \|f(t)\|_2^2\\
\le \int_\Omega \|M(t)\|_F^2 \|f(t)\|_2^2
\le \sup_{t\in\Omega} \|M(t)\|_F^2 \int_\Omega \|f(t)\|_2^2,
$$
which shows
$$
\|\tilde M\|\le \sup_{t\in\Omega} \|M(t)\|_F.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see In the line with $||\tilde{M} f||^2$, how do you make appear the $||M(t)||_F^2$ and $||f(t)||_2^2$? If you take the trace outside (this is irrelevant because the integral gives already a scalar) still have to shift things inside, right?

Comment: See edit. I used the inequality $\|M\|_2\le \|M\|_F$.

Comment: OK I see ($f^\dagger(t) M^\dagger(t) M(t) f(t) = ||M(t)f(t)||_2^2$), great help!